# Mongodb conditional executions' basded on true | false

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

```
return aggregate
                        .Lookup(CollectionAggregation.CollectionLookupName, "UserId", "_id", "asUsers")
                        .Lookup<EffectiveUserAccessRights, EffectiveUserAccessRights, IEnumerable<EffectiveUserAccessRights>, BsonDocument>(
                        foreignCollection: effectiveUserRightsCollection,
                        let: new BsonDocument { { "localCollectionLookupName", $"${localCollectionFieldNameCamelCase}" } },
                        lookupPipeline: new EmptyPipelineDefinition<EffectiveUserAccessRights>().Match(new BsonDocument("$expr",
                        new BsonDocument(
                            "$or", new BsonArray
                                {
                                    new BsonDocument("$eq", new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        $"${isHidden}", true

                                    }),
                                    new BsonDocument("$and", new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        new BsonDocument("$eq", new BsonArray { $"${CollectionIdLookupName}", $"$$localCollectionLookupName" }),
                                        new BsonDocument("$eq", new BsonArray { $"${userIdLookupName}", userIdBson }),
                                        new BsonDocument("$eq", new BsonArray { $"${permissionLookupName}", PermissionEnum.Allow.Name })
                                    })
                                }
                        ))),
                        @as: CollectionAggregation.AccessRightLookupName)
                        .Match(accessRightFilter);
```

In above code trying to execute and condition based on ishiiden ture false but faling due to one of the condition from and block not satisfying so question is if we are using or operator at top then if one of condition is satisfy then and blcok should not get executes